# Failing Kubernetes deployment, expecting char '""' but got char '8'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I have the following Deployment...

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: socket-server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: socket-server
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: socket-server
          image: gcr.io/project-haswell-recon/socket-server:production-production-2
          env:
          - name: PORT
            value: 80
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

But I get the following error when I run `kubectl create -f ./scripts/deployment.yml --namespace production`

`Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "./scripts/deployment.yml": Deployment in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: [pos 321]: json: expect char '"' but got char '8'`

I pretty much copy and pasted this deployment from a previous working deployment, and altered a few details so I'm at a loss as to what this could be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with the number `80`. Here it's within an `EnvVar` context, so it has to be of type `string` and not `int`

Comment: This is a general issue, this can happen for any key. 
Please see the discussion on below link about the same issue:
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/1603